# Bigquery Concurrently Performance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have data size of around `100GB in BQ`, we made the required partition and clustering in our table. So all our queries are simple select only queries with order by clause and having the required partition and cluster filter.

We want to maintain high concurrency (around 1000) and latency of under 1 sec, Is big query the right fit for this ?

Currently the query performance is good but only their google doc they say `100` limit on concurrent queries ?

BI Engine is good fit here ?

Comment: 1000 concurrent queries in the same project? or from different project on the same tables? In addition, why this huge number of concurrent query? Will it increase? Is it a client facing website (or sort of)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
We had API which we have exposed to our end user to query data, data source is single table in one of our gcp project... kind of client facing website

Comment: BigQuery is not designed for that. BI Engine can simulate low latency database, but you won't really be able to scale smoothly. I strongly recommend to look at other data base system, like Cloud SQL or AlloyDB.

Comment: Noted !!!... For this scale and Full text search support should MYSQL will be best fit or  need to go for search solution like ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0):

The query jobs quota for **concurrent queries** is **100 queries in a reservation** as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs). Since your use case is involving around `1000 concurrent queries`, you need to purchase [reservation slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-workload-management) because your concurrent queries are higher than 200. The number of [slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots) that you might want to purchase will depend on **type/size of the queries** you will make e.g `8000-16000 slots for 1000 concurrent queries`. The reservation slots will help increase limits and can prevent the queries to slow down.